unable to pull xcom value in BigQueryOperator
I have a DAG, where i am using BigqueryOperator to create partitioned table, but it is not able to pull the value from Xcom.
def load_job_func(**kwargs):
        table_name = kwargs['table_name']
        load_date = kwargs['load_date']
        Snapshot_Month_Date = kwargs['Snapshot_Month_Date']
        query = "SELECT 1"
        ti = kwargs['ti']
        client = bigquery.Client()
        partition_date = None
        partition_field = None

        if table_name == "printer_data":
            partition_date = load_date.replace("-", "")
            query = f"""SELECT
                        Instance,
                        cast(load_date as Date) as load_date
                        from {BQ_PROJECT}.{BQ_landing_dataset}.{table_name}"""
            partition_field = 'load_date'
        elif table_name == "monthly_print_report":
            partition_date = Snapshot_Month_Date.replace("-", "")
            query = f"""SELECT
                        Location,
                        Serial_Number,
                        
                        cast(load_date as Date) as load_date,
                        cast(Snapshot_Month_Date as date) as Snapshot_Month_Date
                        from {BQ_PROJECT}.{BQ_landing_dataset}.{table_name}"""
            partition_field = 'Snapshot_Month_Date'

        ti.xcom_push(key='partition_date', value=partition_date)
        ti.xcom_push(key='partition_field', value=partition_field)
        return query

    load_job_config = PythonOperator(
        task_id=task_id + "_load_job_config",
        python_callable=load_job_func,
        op_kwargs={"table_name": table_name, "load_date": load_date, 'Snapshot_Month_Date': Snapshot_Month_Date},
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )

    stg_load_task = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id=task_id + "_STG_Load",
        destination_dataset_table=f"{BQ_PROJECT}.{BQ_stg_dataset}.{table_name}${{task_instance.xcom_pull(key='partition_date', task_ids='{task_id}_load_job_config')}}",
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        sql="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='{task_id}_load_job_config') }}".format(task_id=task_id),
        time_partitioning={
            'type': 'DAY',
            'field': "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(key='partition_field', task_ids='{task_id}_load_job_config') }}"
        },
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        allow_large_results=True,
        dag=dag
    )

error :
expects partitioing specification interval (type:day,field:load_date) but input specification is interval ('type':'DAY','field':{task_instance.xcom_pull(key='partition_field',task_ids='printer_data_load_job_config',requirePartitionFilter':'False')})

thanks for help

In the spirit of creating a minimal reproducible example, I suspect that load_job_func could be reduced to return a single hard-coded query. We can then focus on the BigQueryOperator instantiation, and what field can be used for dates.

can you help me with a code snippet, it will be helpful

from an initial glance at the code, time_partitioning={} might be missing format(). please check and update if that is not the case.

It looks like it has been updated now. time_partitioning is no longer initialised to an empty set.

i have added the format but still not working, could you please help me with a sample code piece
